# Can we run decompiled java (jar to java)

Tags: java

I have decompiled a jar file. Can we run this file using eclipse or some other IDE. Or any way to do this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: on running file using eclipse or some other IDE it will again get complied right?

Comment: Well why shouldn't you be able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a number of things, such as:

- whether the original JAR was runnable,
- whether the decompiler produced compilable Java code,
- whether the decompiler produced correct Java code, and
- whether you have all of the dependencies for the decompiled code.

Note that decompilers tend to have difficulty with code that has been obfuscated, and code that uses the latest Java language features.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the decompiler used: some do produce compileable code, some don't. If your decompiler's output can be recompiled you could include it in an eclipse-project and run the main-class (if there is any).

Make sure to have all other dependencies of the jar-file in the build-path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can If it contains `main` method in any of it's `classes`.

Comment: My Decompiled code does not contain main method. I am not able to run this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run the decompiled jar file. Right click on the class which contains main method and select Run as Java application. If required, adjust the classpath (You cand do this in eclipse using java build path and debug settings)